# Setting "Open in New Tab" for Link Control to be checked by default

Tags: block-editor, links

When adding a new link to the visual editor, the default format for the Link Editor is that the "open new tab" is default unchecked.

I am looking for a way to have the checkbox checked automatically as the new default. Is there a way to go about it? When created a new link, it also automatically sets the link to open in the new tab without having to go and edit the link - by checking the "Open In New Tab" checkbox and saving it.

Note that anchor links should be an exception to this new behavior. I just want external links to open in new tabs and not anchor links.

[image]

[image]